# Xamarin app, multiple icons depending on environment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am developing cross plateform mobile app using Xamarin,

We have Prod, Test and Dev source control environment,

Is it possible to have all 3 environment apps installed on a single device?

So I that I can see 3 apps on my device and run it?

Comment: RE: Xamarin.Android - You would have to use three unique package names which equates to three unique .APKs. So although it's possible, it's not really practical.

Comment: ah ha so the icons are related to package name, since the package names are same it always override the other one thanks for the tip

Comment: You would probably want to look into something like HockeyApp which could manage distribution channels for you:

https://hockeyapp.net/features/distribution/